# $facebook->getUser() ALWAYS Returning ID - Can't Logout

Tags: facebook, userid

for some reason no matter what I do, this is always returning a valid ID and Facebook information. To logout, I am using Facebook.Logout, redirecting to a page where I clear ALL cookies including "fbsr_" ones. I even logged out of Facebook manually and it is still returning a valid ID! This is for a Facebook Connect application. Here is my app code,

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if ($uid) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/'+$uid);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      echo $e;
    error_log($e);
    $uid = NULL;
  }
}
```

Then my PHP logout code,

```
$app_id="XXXX";
session_name('QEW');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
$facebook->destroySession();
if (isset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id])) 
{
      setcookie('fbsr_' . $app_id, $_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id], time() - 3600, "/");
      setcookie('PHPSESSID', $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'], time() - 3600, "/");

      unset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id]);   
      unset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
}
```

**EDIT**
My Javascript code,

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ 
        appId:'XXX', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true, oauth:true,
        channelURL:'~~.com/channel.html'
        });
};
(function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
          }());
function login(io)
{
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
    {
        if(response.status == 'connected')
        {
            if(io==1)
            {
                FB.login(function(response) 
                {
                  if (response.authResponse) 
                  {
                     cU(response.authResponse.userID);
                  }
                },{scope:'email'});
            }
            else
            {
                FB.logout(function(response){});
                window.location="./logout.php";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FB.login(function(response) 
            {
              if (response.authResponse) 
              {
                 cU(response.authResponse.userID);
              }
            },{scope:'email'});
        }
    });
}
```

Then after "logging out", I go to another page that calls the first block of code again, and it just repopulates the cookies because it gets a valid user id back. how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Do you use client-side FB JS API?

Comment: I am grabbing their library from the server. I edited my code into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You delete cookie by php. After that on next request JS API restores it.

The only and valid way to **logout** from facebook is to redirect user to logout url:

```
echo $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

or the same from the client JS API [FB.logout();](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/)

Comment: Ah I see what's happening. But even using that link still causes the API to restore it when I come back to the page. It doesn't permanently log me out. Basically what happens is that I am on the homepage and click the logout button, that uses the FB.Logout to log me out, then after that, it calls logout.php, then reloads the homepage again. When it reloads the homepage again is when it is catching the API call in the JS to create it again. Using the logout URL does the same thing, right when it loads the homepage again, it is repopulated.

Comment: @Tanner: as long as you **redirect** user to logout page - user is being logged out from facebook, so you **should** lost the session in your app

Comment: To be honest I can't even get facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=... to even work through the browser. It just keeps redirecting to /home.php :\

Comment: What `echo $facebook->getLogoutUrl();` returns?

Comment: I was using this function,

`$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'http://www.~~.com/logout.php'));`

Which made $logoutURL = https://www.facebook.com/logout.php/next=~~&access_token=...

Comment: @Tanner: and redirecting to that url logs user out (proven million times)

Comment: The problem it was not logging me out of Facebook was because it was open in a minimized window, figures... However as I said before, even logged out of Facebook, getUser is STILL populated somehow. Any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: @Tanner: to be clear I haven't experienced such behaviour and for me logout just worked fine. Have no time to set up blank application to check it now, sorry. But you could try facebook php sdk example. I doubt that it doesn't work